# Undefined \beamer@cramped when using itemize in the footline of a beamer document

Tags: beamer, header-footer

For a poster I would like to have a list in the footline. Unfortunately this seems to trigger a bug in beamer:

```
./mwe.tex:10: Undefined control sequence.
\\itemize ...ix item}##1}}}}} \fi \beamer@cramped
                                                  \raggedright \beamer@first...
```

This MWE shows the problem. Normal text (like the commented word) w/o itemize work fine.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foo
    \end{itemize}
    % foowo
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        bar
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unlike in [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251982) I have not forgotten to add a frame (adding it to the footline itself is of course not appropriate).
I am using beamer 2017/01/22 v3.40.
How to make this work, what's the underlying cause in beamer and how to correct it?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@cramped{}%%%%%%
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foo
    \end{itemize}
    % foowo
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    bar
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

it is defined by `\frame{...}` but there is no frame in the footline